# Actionscript RegExp positions and lengths of all matches in one call

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, position

How can I locate all positions of some word in text in one call using regular expressions in actionscript.

In example, I have this regular expression:

```
var wordsRegExp:RegExp = /[^a-zA-Z0-9]?(include|exclude)[^a-zA-Z0-9]?/g;
```

and it finds words "include" and "exclude" in text.

I am using

```
var match:Array;
match = wordsRegExp.exec(text)
```

to locate the words, but it finds first one first. I need to find all words "include" and "exclude" and there position so i do this:

```
    var res:Array = new Array();
    var match:Array;
    while (match = wordsRegExp.exec(text)) {
        res[res.length]=match;
    }
```

And this does the trick, BUT very very slow for large amount of text. I was searching for some other method and didn't find it.

Please help and thanks in advance.

```
EDIT: I tried var arr:Array = text.match(wordsRegExp);
it finds all words, but not there positions in string
```

Comment: But is it faster if you use `String.match()`?

Comment: Yes, much faser. It finds every "include" and "exclude" in text, but doesn't give their positions (indexes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's the nature of the beast. I don't know what you mean with "large amount of text", but if you want better performance, you should write your own parsing function. This shouldn't be that complicated, as your search expression is fairly simple.

I've never compared the performance of the `String` search functions and `RegExp`, because I thought there are based on the same implementation. If `String.match()` is faster, then you should try `String.search()`. With the index you could compute the substring for the next search iteration.

Comment: I'm doing script highlighting in flex. This is just simple example what i need. Instead of "include" and "exclude" I'll have approximately 150 keywords. And scripts are between 5000 and 6000 lines of code. I found some "plugins" but they are parsing on every change whole text. I have some idea how to make it faster, but I'm stuck here.

Comment: @Stefan.Nikolic From the algorithmic perspective it's not a big difference if you write a parser to extract **identifiers** and then compare them with 2 or 150 keywords.

Comment: I know that. I'm planning to paint all keywords blue. So i need to know where are those keywords. This is only the problem when large amount of code is paste in one moment. Currently I'm trying to kill two flies with one hit with String.replace.

I need to put every keyword between <span color="#0000FF"> and </span>

Answer (score -2):

Found this on the **[help.adobe.com](http://help.adobe.com/)** site,...

**["Methods for using regular expressions with strings: The exec() method"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ea8.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e77)**

… The array also includes an index property, indicating the index position of the start of the substring match …

```
var pattern:RegExp = /\w*sh\w*/gi; 
var str:String = "She sells seashells by the seashore"; 
var result:Array = pattern.exec(str); 

while (result != null) 
{ 
    trace(result.index, "\t", pattern.lastIndex, "\t", result); 
result = pattern.exec(str); 
} 
//output:  
// 0      3      She 
// 10      19      seashells 
// 27      35      seashore
```

Comment: Did you even **BOTHER** to read the question? He wants to match all occurrences in ONE call. This answer is completely unrelated to the question, and the fact that you are a new member does not give you license to renew an old, closed question with an unacceptable answer. I suggest you read the [faq], check how your behaviour here should be.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi You are right, but you could be more respectful towards new users.